# Discriminating between two identical elements when they are both "displayed" and "enabled" but only one is actually visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, android, mobile-automation, android-automation

I am currently automating tests for a native app and I have some issues with "ghosts" elements. By "ghosts elements" I mean elements that are in the code and *technically* on the page but aren't visible to the user.

I am testing using Android and I don't know if the issue would also be present with iOS.

Simply put, I want to click on element X but instead I end up clicking on element Y **who isn't visible to the user** because X and Y share the same specifications (same text, same element type/class).

I have tried ignoring the element Y by using "isDisplayed()" and "isEnabled()" but it seems like both X and Y are displayed and enabled (even though only X is actually visible to the user).

**Is there any way I can discriminate between X and Y using the fact that one is visible to the user and the other isn't?** If possible, I don't want to ask the devs to change the code of the app.

If it helps, here is how the app ended up with "ghost elements":

1. Apps open page 1, page 1 has element Y
2. Apps open page 2, page 2 is different that page 1 but have element X who is the same as element Y from page 1
3. We are now on page 2 but page 1 didn't disappear and is just "behind" page 2.

I found [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8200) and [that](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8208) who seem to be about the same issue, but there is no solution on how to fix it.

---

PS: I am using Java but I would accept answers in any language.

Comment: What to you mean under `visible`? The second element is on the page but out of the current view port?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I mean "visible for the user". It's like both elements are here but there is something on top of element Y so only element X is visible.

Comment: Oh I see. That means some other element overlaps one of those two so that it is like behind it?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Yes (except that "some other element" is more like a full page, but yes).

Comment: I am not sure how different mobile UI is from web but I believe there is a hierarchy of elements (DOM) and they have to split on some level. Isn't it true?

Comment: @AlexeyR. It's true indeed. But if anything changes on the page, the hierarchy will change too. So I can't really use that to find my element.

Comment: For now, I have asked the dev to add a unique id for each page, so I can then search the element by the XPAth "//myPageId//*[contains(@text, myText)]". But would rather have a solution that doesn't involve asking something from the devs

Comment: Cant you just take topmost page using xpath?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Maybe? I'm not sure I know how to do that or if it's even possible.

Comment: Okay, I'll form my assumption in the answer and we'll see if it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the UI has a certain hierarchy and normally object hierarchy has ordered structure (like XML). That means that when you add an element you don't just add it to a random place but to a specific place. Usually it is either the top or the bottom of outer container.

So assume you have the structure like this:

```xml
<app>
  <page>
    <element>bottom</element>
  </page>  
  <page>
    <element>top</element>
  </page>  
</app>
```

If the new page added is being added to the top, then you can access it with `/app/page[1]/element`

If the new page added is being added to the bottom, then you can access it with `/app/page[last()]/element`

Comment: FYI, it does seem like each new page is added at the bottom (I'm just hoping that will be a consistent behavior)

Comment: Anyway UI framework has to know which page is to render. So the page has to have any property that would help renderer do distinguish it. It is either a position or a attribute of the page.